# Set root password during autoinstall

Tags: user-data

Is it possible to set up the root password using Ubuntu autoinstall (i.e. user-data)?

I tried:

```
user-data:
    disable_root: false
    chpasswd:
      list: |
        root:$6$AYtLXyyVZAea2aLJ$UQxW1cz2vWWNn.17.3QYH5TxZqIMGoLJCpqbBTfClhUKxqouYn7/Yc5Jsq.bCeK0VDLPxbL6xzfJ0xqTb6MLk.
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
version: 1
user-data:
    disable_root: false
identity:
    hostname: hostname
    username: root
    password: $6$AYtLXyyVZAea2aLJ$UQxW1cz2vWWNn.17.3QYH5TxZqIMGoLJCpqbBTfClhUKxqouYn7/Yc5Jsq.bCeK0VDLPxbL6xzfJ0xqTb6MLk.
```

Comment: Didn't work for me!

Comment: Because you do not know the password...

Comment: I've changed it to my own, though still doesn't work. Looks to me as identity and user-data blocks cannot be  used together. An identity block causes user-data to be ignored.

Comment: Here is a more complete example file that shows off most features: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall
`user-data` and `identity` together